# CSS display the menu wrongly

Tags: css

This code suppose to display Movies when the mouse places on it but the issue here is that the movie menu displays wherever the mouse placed in the header?

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul> class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                     <li>
                          <a href="#">Movies</a>

                         <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>

            </ul>
```

CSS Code

```
.nav .sub-menu {      

     display:none;
}

.nav:hover .sub-menu {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the hover to the movie element. This works:

HTML:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                     <li id="movies">
                          <a href="#">Movies</a>

                         <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>

            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav .sub-menu {      

         display:none;
    }

    #movies:hover .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    }
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yd8ddv4x/

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseOver instead of hover as the latter is not uniformly supported